# Выбор div без имени

Tags: javascript, css

Есть ли способ изменить свойства блока, в конструкции где идет множество соседних безымянных блоков.

```
<div class="name">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> //изменения только в этом блоке
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last-child` - задает оформление последнего элемента своего родителя

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.name  div {
  background: blue;
}

.name div:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
</div>
```